# laco de repeticao

Tags: javascript

estou tentando reduzir o codigo js pois tenho 9 inputs desses,mas o laco for nao funciona por algum motivo que desconheco, ao escrever no input tem que mudar oq esta escrito no

basicamente quero uma maneira de automatizar o processo, ja que as unicas coisas que muda no js e #input_titulo_imagem_1, #input_titulo_imagem_2 e a assim vai....

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="titulo_imagem_1" id="input_titulo_imagem_1" placeholder="Titulo Primeira Imagem" required/>
    <small id="menuHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        Escreva o Titulo da imagem.
    </small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="titulo_imagem_2" id="input_titulo_imagem_2" placeholder="Titulo Segunda Imagem" required/>
    <small id="menuHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        Escreva o Titulo da imagem.
    </small>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <img src="../img/natureza2.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="titulo_imagem_1">Titulo Primeira Imagem</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img src="../img/natureza2.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="titulo_imagem_2">Titulo Segunda Imagem</h5>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        $('#input_titulo_imagem_' + i).on('change', function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('#titulo_imagem_' + i).text(value);
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um seletor para facilitar o seu trabalho, no exemplo abaixo eu crio um algoritmo utilizando o jQuery para escutar o `keyup` e o `change` de todos os elementos que possuam a propriedade `data-text-to`.

Para usar basta adicionar nos inputs a propriedade `data-text-to` com o query selector que deseja enviar o texto.

> Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" data-text-to="#id_conteudo_1" />
<h5 id="id_conteudo_1"></h5>
<br/>
<input type="text" data-text-to="#id_conteudo_2" />
<h5 id="id_conteudo_2"></h5>

<script>
  // criando selector para enviar texto para outro elemento.
  $('body').on('change, keyup', '[data-to-text]', function () {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-to-text');
    var elem = $(selector);
    if(elem.length) {
      elem.text($(this).val());
    }
  });
</script>
```

No seu caso, bastaria nos inputs você inserir nos inputs o `data-text-to` com o id dos `h5` que receberiam o conteúdo.

Exemplo JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/n5gpwmz0/2/

Answer (score 0):

Olá. O seu código não funciona porque o `i` usado dentro do evento de `change` é o mesmo usado no `for`. Quando o evento é chamado, o valor de `i` vai ser sempre igual a `10` (experimente dar um `console.log(i)` dentro do evento de `change`). Além disso, o evento adequado é `input` e não `change`. Coloquei um código abaixo em que conserto esse problema de escopo da variável `i` e modifico o evento.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    (function(j){
      $('#input_titulo_imagem_' + j).on('input', function() {
          var value = $(this).val();
          $('#titulo_imagem_' + j).text(value);
      });
    })(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="titulo_imagem_1" id="input_titulo_imagem_1" placeholder="Titulo Primeira Imagem" required/>
    <small id="menuHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        Escreva o Titulo da imagem.
    </small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="titulo_imagem_2" id="input_titulo_imagem_2" placeholder="Titulo Segunda Imagem" required/>
    <small id="menuHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
        Escreva o Titulo da imagem.
    </small>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <img src="../img/natureza2.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="titulo_imagem_1">Titulo Primeira Imagem</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img src="../img/natureza2.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="titulo_imagem_2">Titulo Segunda Imagem</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Você pode ler mais sobre esse problema de uso de variáveis em *callbacks* e *loops* [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377971/javascript-how-to-work-with-the-iterator-in-a-for-loop-with-callbacks).

> Acredito que fazer como o Hiago Souza comentou é melhor que usando um `for`.